# epstopdf loose greek symbole

Tags: pdf, conventions

I'm generating a pdf using gnuplot this way:

```
set term postscript color eps enhanced 15
set out '| epstopdf --filter --outfile=SD.pdf' 
replot
set out
```

Whereas the eps file generated contains the right Greek symbol (π) the pdf generated by epstopdf contains the "not equal" symbol  instead.
If I disable gsview (via --nogs) I get a hugly pdf with the right symbol.
The issue seems to come from GS but I've no idea how to overcome it.

Note that ps2pdf has the same issue.

Can someone tell me how to generate a good quality pdf from a encapsulate postscript without loosing Greek symbols?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant "Note that ..."

Comment: No need to feel sorry, just [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/273294/edit) your question and correct.